# Can access IP address of domain via mobile but not wifi

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, dns

I have updated the A record of my domain name and I understand it takes time to propagate through the world's DNS servers.

Looks like my mobile phone internet provider has updated their DNS servers but my home ISP has not.

My question is why can I not access my domain by typing in the IP address directly on my home internet, but I can when connected to mobile internet?

I thought, if it's a DNS issue, then typing the IP address directly into the browser URL bar should resolve and display the website, just as it does successfully on mobile, but it does not work on wifi and just shows 'This site can’t be reached [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) refused to connect'

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work"? Have you tried pinging the IP?

Comment: @Gaberocksall just updated it

Comment: What do DNS tools such as `dig` say about the state of your DNS?  What type of hosting are you using?  What web server?  What is your web server configuration?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.